Designing a multi-threaded chat server
I am designing a multi-threaded chat server in C and I am using TCP. I am using a combination of event-polling using kqueue() and a thread pool. I monitor the sockets for read/write and when a socket is ready, that respective task is queued to the thread pool's task queue. However, I want to avoid multiple threads calling recv() on the same socket concurrently or send() on the same socket concurrently.
I thought of using a mutex on each socket, but this poses concurrency problems as I would have to unlock/lock the mutex for each user (socket) that I want to send a message to. I was wondering if there is a way to avoid this, or is my design of the server using a thread pool combined with socket polling faulty? I wanted to add that I am trying to avoid a one-thread-per-client model as a challenge and try a different approach.

You don't necessarily need a sync object per socket - just a flag. If a thread wants to do something with a socket, it checks the socket's flag. If it's clear, a common mutex is acquired. If the flag is still clear the thread sets the flag and releases the mutex, otherwise it must release the mutex and not use the socket. Flag is cleared when the thread is done with the socket operation.

The standard way to design multi-threaded application with communication with outside world is to put recv() into the main loop of main thread, received message is then used to create a new thread. That thread process just one message, call send() (it is already thread safe and you do not need to do manual mutex handling). Once the processing thread finished with its message, the thread just closes.
If you want to have a pool of threads so each of them survive for several messages then you have two options:

Each thread has its own queue and once the main loop receives a new message it should read message header, decide which thread supposed to process this particular message and push it into the queue of that thread. You will need each queue to be mutex-lockable to ensure that main thread and processing thread are working with the queue safely.
All threads can share same queue, but then they have to "wake up" on each addition to the queue, scan it for "my messages", and pick them up. In this case, the queue is actually more like a bus. This approach requires just one mutex on the queue/bus, but all threads will work with it and this can be a bottleneck.

In both cases, the recv() is still lives in the main loop of main thread. And each thread is just using send() to send reply.

Won't the main loop get slow from calling recv() on many sockets? What is the point of doing half the mesage processing on one thread and then half with the thread pool, wouldn't it be better at that point to just design a single-threaded event-polling server?

@threads23 recv() is working on one socket. If you want to receive on many sockets, you can combine them all into one poll() and then run recv() on the socket with data. Or you can do recv() in threads, then each thread would have its own recv/send pair. But multi-socket work is a different animal with different issues. You indicated in original post multi-threaded, but with single socket. If you think to have one receiver socket, and multiple sending - not a good idea, after all, number of sockets is limited by number of ports.

Sorry for the misunderstanding, I intend to have a socket for recv() and send() for each client. Right now what I do is I poll the sockets for read and write and call send() recv() respectively using the thread pool.

If you have multiple incoming sockets, then there is no real need to do a multi-threaded application. You can just create a single-thread with recv()/send() and just run this application multiple times - one time for each socket. Much easier to write then multi-threaded, and not much harder to setup end product to work.

TL;DR: using one-shot- or dispatch-flagged events is both a practical necessity for your design and a solution to the problem you ask about.

However, I want to avoid multiple threads calling recv() on the same socket concurrently or send() on the same socket concurrently.

Note that

POSIX send() and recv() are atomic, so concurrent send()s and / or recv()s on the same socket are thread safe, as POSIX defines that term.  They won't interfere with each other per se.  However, performing two or more concurrent recv() on the same socket might occasionally give an appearance of the data arriving out of order.  Two or more concurrent send()s on the same socket might actually send the data out of order.

However, there should be no issue at all with send()ing concurrently with recv()ing on the same TCP socket.  TCP is full-duplex.  You don't need writes to exclude reading or vice versa.

TCP is also stream-oriented, not message oriented.  That means that it is not safe to assume that the boundaries of your read()s / recv()s line up with the boundaries of the remote peer's write()s / send()s. It also means that you cannot safely rely on all available data to be transferred in a single recv() or send() call.

A kqueue read filter detects whether there is currently data available to read, and a write filter detects whether there is currently space available to write.  If the thread calling kqueue dispatches events to other threads instead of handling them itself then chances are good that the conditions that trigger those events will still prevail when the kqueue thread calls kevent() again, even if no additional data has been received or no additional write buffer space has opened.


Together, those suggest the following design characteristics for a system with the constraints given in the question:

Your EVFILT_READ and EVFILTER_WRITE events must be removed (EV_ONESHOT flag) or disabled (EV_DISPATCH flag) when they fire to avoid duplicate events being generated, creating a whole lot of needless work for your entire system.

A thread processing a read or write event should keep reading until there is no more data available transfer or no more capacity to transfer it.  This will avoid needless extra round-trips through kqueue and your thread pool's task queue.

The sockets should be set non-blocking, so that the threads handling reads and writes can detect the exhaustion of the read buffer or fill of the write buffer without blocking.

When a thread completes a read task it re-registers the corresponding read event with kqueue (if using one-shot) or re-enables it (if using dispatch).  Similar when a thread completes a write task.


You don't then need any extra synchronization objects to avoid concurrent reads on the same socket or concurrent writes on the same socket.  These should be appropriately serialized by use of relevant kqueue features alone.

Thanks for the in depth explanation. I was wondering though, if two threads call recv() on the same socket, isn’t it possible that if the message “hello” was sent, thread 1 could read “he” and thread two could read “llo”? Or will this be resolved through your suggested design? I’m referring to point 3 above about TCP being stream oriented.

@threads23, POSIX does not exclude that possibility, but in practice you will not see it for such a short message, transmitted in the same packet.  And you especially will not see it if you follow the advice given in this answer, because then you will not have two threads trying to recv() from the same socket at the same time in the first place.  At least, not in response to kqueue events.

On the other hand, @threads23, you need to bear in mind my point (3): TCP is stream oriented.  There are no message boundaries in TCP communication, unless you layer them on top yourself, as part of an application-layer protocol.  Who's to say, then, that it would be wrong to process "he" separately from "llo"?

"When a thread completes a read task it re-registers the corresponding read event with kqueue (if using one-shot) or re-enables it (if using dispatch). Similar when a thread completes a write task."
I am assuming I have to use a mutex to lock the list of kevent structs passed to kevent(), if my read/write tasks are running in different threads?

Only if that list is shared between different threads, @threads23, and I don't see any reason why it should be.  It would be easy and natural for each thread to use its own.  Especially since the pooled threads only ever need a single-element list each.

Could you elaborate please? Right now in my main thread I have one list of kevent structs that kevent() uses. How would each thread have its own list, and one that is single element? Wouldn’t this be one thread per socket?

@threads23, it is not the identity of a struct kevent object that is significant to kevent(), but only its contents.  The worker threads simply don't need to use the same objects that the main thread does, not even for instructing kevent about the same FDs.  A natural way for the threads to have their own would be to make them local variables of the thread function.
